# What does the logistic calibration line represent on the calibration plot made by val.plot function (from rms package in R)?

Tags: r, logistic, calibration

I've been trying to make calibration plots/curves for a logistic regression model in R to mimic what I'm doing in a statistics course--but the class uses SAS with proc sgplot.

I think I've figured it out using the rms package in R using the val.prob function.

mlm being the logistic regression model, and event containing the actual events recorded as 0s or 1s. All variables ending with f are factored categorical variables.

`mlm <- glm(eventf~x1f + x2f + x3, family = binomial, data)
val.prob(p = fitted(mlm), y = data$event)`

[image: val.prob output]

So I get this plot, but I can't figure out what the logistic calibration line is supposed to be? It looks near identical to the Ideal, and the Nonparametric I assume is the loess smoothed calibration plot.

On that note, does anybody know how to add confidence bands around the Nonparametric line?